# How can I verify that a value is present in an array (list) in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, list, find

I have a list of possible values:

```
@a = qw(foo bar baz);
```

How do I check in a concise way that a value `$val` is present or absent in `@a`?

An obvious implementation is to loop over the list, but I am sure [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

---

Thanks to all who answered! The three answers I would like to highlight are:

1. The accepted answer - the most "built-in" and backward-compatible way.
2. [RET's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720482/how-to-verify-that-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-list-in-perl/720530#720530) is the cleanest, but only good for Perl 5.10 and later.
3. [draegtun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720482/how-to-verify-that-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-list-in-perl/720812#720812) is (possibly) a bit faster, but requires using an additional module. I do not like adding dependencies if I can avoid them, and in this case do not need the performance difference, but if you have a 1,000,000-element list you might want to give this answer a try.

Comment: I'm not sure that I see the dependency issue with List::Util. It's standard with Perl and if you use it with qw/first/ (as Draegtun did), you import only the one subroutine.

Comment: It's not an issue per se, it's more of a personal preference.

Comment: There is no dependency issue with the List::Util answer.  If it was me, that would be the accepted answer.  Unwillinglness to use core modules strikes me as a preference rooted in superstition.  In this case grep {} is almost as good though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perl's bulit in grep() function is designed to do this.

```
@matches = grep( /^MyItem$/, @someArray );
```

or you can insert any expression into the matcher

```
@matches = grep( $_ == $val, @a );
```

Answer (score 40):

If you have perl 5.10, use the [smart-match operator](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/pod/perlsyn.pod#Smart_matching_in_detail) ~~

`print "Exist\n" if $var ~~ @array;`

It's almost magic.

Comment: NB. From 5.10.1 the semantics have changed a little and it needs to be:  `if $var ~~ @array`.  To help I think of `~~` as `in`.  ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html#Smart-match-changes

Comment: My perldoc url is no longer valid.  Here is fixed one: http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/pod/perl5101delta.pod#Smart_match_changes

Answer (score 18):

This is answered in [perlfaq4](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html)'s answer to ["How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?"](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How_can_I_tell_wheth).

To search the perlfaq, you could search through the list of all questions in [perlfaq](http://faq.perl.org/) using your favorite browser.

From the command line, you can use the -q switch to perldoc to search for keywords. You would have found your answer by searching for "list":

```
perldoc -q list
```

---

(portions of this answer contributed by Anno Siegel and brian d foy)

Hearing the word "in" is an indication that you probably should have used a hash, not a list or array, to store your data. Hashes are designed to answer this question quickly and efficiently. Arrays aren't.

That being said, there are several ways to approach this. In Perl 5.10 and later, you can use the smart match operator to check that an item is contained in an array or a hash:

```
use 5.010;

if( $item ~~ @array )
    {
    say "The array contains $item"
    }

if( $item ~~ %hash )
    {
    say "The hash contains $item"
    }
```

With earlier versions of Perl, you have to do a bit more work. If you are going to make this query many times over arbitrary string values, the fastest way is probably to invert the original array and maintain a hash whose keys are the first array's values:

```
@blues = qw/azure cerulean teal turquoise lapis-lazuli/;
%is_blue = ();
for (@blues) { $is_blue{$_} = 1 }
```

Now you can check whether $is_blue{$some_color}. It might have been a good idea to keep the blues all in a hash in the first place.

If the values are all small integers, you could use a simple indexed array. This kind of an array will take up less space:

```
@primes = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31);
@is_tiny_prime = ();
for (@primes) { $is_tiny_prime[$_] = 1 }
# or simply  @istiny_prime[@primes] = (1) x @primes;
```

Now you check whether $is_tiny_prime[$some_number].

If the values in question are integers instead of strings, you can save quite a lot of space by using bit strings instead:

```
@articles = ( 1..10, 150..2000, 2017 );
undef $read;
for (@articles) { vec($read,$_,1) = 1 }
```

Now check whether vec($read,$n,1) is true for some $n.

These methods guarantee fast individual tests but require a re-organization of the original list or array. They only pay off if you have to test multiple values against the same array.

If you are testing only once, the standard module List::Util exports the function first for this purpose. It works by stopping once it finds the element. It's written in C for speed, and its Perl equivalent looks like this subroutine:

```
sub first (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    foreach (@_) {
        return $_ if &{$code}();
    }
    undef;
}
```

If speed is of little concern, the common idiom uses grep in scalar context (which returns the number of items that passed its condition) to traverse the entire list. This does have the benefit of telling you how many matches it found, though.

```
my $is_there = grep $_ eq $whatever, @array;
```

If you want to actually extract the matching elements, simply use grep in list context.

```
my @matches = grep $_ eq $whatever, @array;
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the *first* function from [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/List/Util.pm) which comes as standard with Perl....

```
use List::Util qw/first/;

my @a = qw(foo bar baz);
if ( first { $_ eq 'bar' } @a ) { say "Found bar!" }
```

NB. *first* returns the first element it finds and so doesn't have to iterate through the complete list (which is what *grep* will do).

Comment: per foolishbrat, if using an imported sub, I would prefer List::MoreUtil::any() because the concept ("Returns a true value if any item in LIST meets the criterion") is semantically a better match to the question than first() ("returns the first element where the result from BLOCK is a true value.")

Comment: List::Util::first() has the advantage of being core module (ie. ubiquitous).  If I were looking for CPAN options then I would seriously consider Perl6::Junction::any...  if ( any(@a) eq 'baz' ) {}

Answer (score 8):

One possible approach is to use List::MoreUtils 'any' function.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/any/;

my @array = qw(foo bar baz);

print "Exist\n" if any {($_ eq "foo")} @array;
```

**Update**: corrected based on zoul's comment.

Comment: Defined("foo") is always true, did You mean $_ eq 'foo'?

Comment: I keep taking off the -1 I gave you and it keeps putting it back on... Hope it stays off this (3rd) time!

Answer (score 5):

Interesting solution, especially for repeated searching:

```
my %hash;
map { $hash{$_}++ } @a;
print $hash{$val};
```

Comment: Zoul's suggestion about a hash is pretty close to optimal however I would suggest that as you add and remove values to your array during the course of your program add and remove those value in your hash.

Comment: Also, although this works and is common, some people (myself included I guess) will complain about using map in a void context.  Why not $hash{$_}++ for @a instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -e '@a = qw(foo bar baz);$val="bar";
if (grep{$_ eq $val} @a) {
  print "found"
} else {
  print "not found"
}'
```

found

```
$val='baq';
```

not found

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like unnecessary dependency, implement `any` or `first` yourself

```
sub first (&@) {
  my $code = shift;
  $code->() and return $_ foreach @_;
  undef
}

sub any (&@) {
  my $code = shift;
  $code->() and return 1 foreach @_;
  undef
}
```