# How can I check if a value is in a list in Perl?

Tags: perl, list, hash, arrays

I have a file in which every line is an integer which represents an id. What I want to do is just check whether some specific ids are in this list.
But the code didn't work. It never tells me it exists even if 123 is a line in that file. I don't know why? Help appreciated.

```
open (FILE, "list.txt") or die ("unable to open !");

    my @data=<FILE>;

    my %lookup  =map {chop($_) => undef} @data;

    my $element= '123';
    if (exists $lookup{$element})
    {
        print "Exists";
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720482/how-can-i-verify-that-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-list-in-perl

Comment: `chop($_)` evaluates to the last character of `$_`. You probably wanted to say `map { chop; $_ => undef } @data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl 5.10 and up, you can also use the smart match operator:

```
my $id = get_id_to_check_for();
open my $fh, '<', 'list.txt' or die "unable to open list.txt: $!";
chomp( my @data = <$fh> );
print "Id found!" if $id ~~ @data;
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to ensure you make your hash correctly. The very outdated [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) isn't what you want to use. Use [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) instead, and use it on the entire array at once and before you create the hash:

```
 open my $fh, '<', 'list.txt' or die "unable to open list.txt: $!";
 chomp( my @data = <$fh> );
 my $hash = map { $_, 1 } @data;
```

Answer (score 2):

[perldoc -q contain](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array?)

Answer (score 2):

`chop` returns the character it chopped, not what was left behind. You perhaps want something like this:

`my %lookup = map { substr($_,0,-1) => undef } @data;`

However, generally, you should consider using `chomp` instead of `chop` to do a more intelligent CRLF removal, so you'd end up with a line like this:

`my %lookup  =map {chomp; $_ => undef } @data;`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that chop returns the character chopped, not the resulting string, so you're creating a hash with a single entry for newline. This would be obvious in debugging if you used Data::Dumper to output the resulting hash.

Try this instead:

```
my @data=<FILE>;
chomp @data;

my %lookup = map {$_ => undef} @data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work... it uses `first` in List::Util to do the searching, and eliminates the initial `map` (this is assuming you don't need to store the values for something else immediately after).  The `chomp` is done while searching for the value; see [perldoc -f chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

```
use List::Util 'first';
open (my $fh, 'list.txt') or die 'unable to open list.txt!';

my @elements = <$fh>;

my $element = '123';
if (first { chomp; $_ eq $element } @elements)
{
    print "Exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one may not exactly match your specific problem,
but if your integer numbers need to be
counted, you might even use the good
old "canonical" perl approach:

```
 open my $fh, '<', 'list.txt' or die "unable to open list.txt: $!";

 my %lookup;
 while( <$fh> ) { chomp; $lookup{$_}++ }   # this will count occurences if ints

 my $element = '123';
 if( exists $lookup{$element} ) {
    print "$element $lookup{$element} times there\n" 
 }
```

This might even be in some circumstances faster than
solutions with intermediate array.

Regards

rbo